Withdraw Pepe Unchained from smart call contract
I hope someone can help cause I have no clue what I’m doing. I bought into the Pepe unchained presale and staked my tokens. I have since claimed my staking rewards via my trust wallet however the tokens are locked into a smart call contract and I don’t know how to withdraw them. The transaction hash is
0xa6f08d6c698a09250edc474ce7869e80b4b29c9b1d1e984de346c2229bc28680

You should ask in the Pepe Unchained community instead.
